# Shiny Data Table output duplicating certain columns, weird error

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I'm trying to output a data table to a Shiny UI and it produces a weird error which I copy below.  It attempts to take the 3 columns and duplicates them down, but all other columns are fine.  I checked the back-end data that is output and it is fine, it's only when displaying that some weird issue occurs.  The 3 columns contains string, int, int.

```
Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , j, value = list("random string here that's copied down.",  :
  provided 7 variables to replace 1 variables
Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , j, value = list(1, 3, 3, 450, 2,  :
  provided 7 variables to replace 1 variables
```

The logic flows like this:

```
reactive_data <- eventReactive(  input$action, {   return(data)      })

  output$view <- DT::renderDataTable({
    reactive_data()
     }#, digits = 0),
    ,options = list(scrollX = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE,
                    columnDefs =list(list(width = '500px', targets = list(6))),
                    searching = FALSE)
  )
```

Output data looks like:

```
  Index Number       Company Name                                            Case Name Filing Date Circuit   Bloomberg Sector
1:       105115 A123 Systems, Inc. case name 1  9/27/2013     2nd     random segment
2:       105138 Tesla Motors, Inc. case name 2   11/8/2013     9th C  random segment2
      Case Status        Snippet                             Freq              Freq
1: CASE DISMISSED          random string                      1                     3
2: CASE DISMISSED          random string                    1                   3
```

As you can see, columns 1 through 7 (hard to see in output) are different, which they should be.  But when OUTPUTING columns 8-10 duplicate the first row to all subsequent rows below for JUST those columns and produces the warning/error I copy above.  The actual data that's saved is the correct data for all columns but the visual output in shiny app does this random duplication thing.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. In my case it was because the columns in my data frame were lists instead of vectors. I had to first convert all columns in my data frame to character vectors and then convert it to a data frame (since the map functions produces a list):

```
library(purrr) # for map function
data <- map(reactive_data(), as.character) %>% data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE}
```